# SharePoint Search Issue for Anonymous User

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

We have facing a issue with search for public website having anonymous access. We are getting below unexpected error in logs

> The request has been determined to be anonymous but the
> WindowsIdentity does not match the anonymous user.

We have tried all the available solutions on google but no luck.

Other errors with High severity are:

> Exception occured in scope
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries.
> Exception=System.InvalidOperationException: The security token request
> cannot be completed.
>
> Original error: System.InvalidOperationException: The security token
> request cannot be completed.
>
> Original error: System.InvalidOperationException: The security token
> request cannot be completed.      at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForServiceContext(Uri
> contextUri)      at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.SPChannelFactoryOperations.InternalCreateChannelActingAsLoggedOnUser[TChannel](ChannelFactory`1 factory, EndpointAddress address, Uri via)      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetChannel(Uri address, Boolean asService, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds)      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoSpLoadBalancedUriWsOp[T](WebServiceBackedOperation`1
> webServiceCall, Boolean asService, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
> wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, String operationName)      at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.DoWebServiceBackedOperation[T](String
> operationName, Boolean asService, Int32 timeoutInMilliseconds, Int32
> wcfTimeoutInMilliseconds, WebServiceBackedOperation`1 webServiceCall)  at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.IsUrlMappingCachedWithHash(Guid subscriptionId, SPUrlZone zone, String siteCollectionHash)      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.UpdateQueryProperties(SsaOperationFlags operationFlags, QueryProperties properties, VariantConfigurationSnapshot snapshot, SPContext context)      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplicationProxy.Execute(QueryProperties properties)      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.Query.ExecuteQuery()      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueryInternal(Query query)      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQuery(Query query)      at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries(Dictionary`2
> queries, Boolean handleExceptions)      at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.RunWithRemoteAPIsPermission[T](Func`1
> f)      at
> Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchExecutor.ExecuteQueries_Client(String[]
> queryIds, Query[] queries, Boolean handleExceptions)      at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerStub.InvokeMethodWithMonitoredScope(Object
> target, String methodName, XmlNodeList args, ProxyContext
> proxyContext, Boolean& isVoid)      at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.InvokeMethod(Object
> obj, String methodName, XmlNodeList xmlargs, Boolean& isVoid)      at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessMethod(XmlElement
> xe)      at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessStatements(XmlNode
> xe)      at
> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientMethodsProcessor.ProcessExceptionHandlingScope(XmlElement
> xe)

Looking forward for support.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue posts for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/84f6bf27-b8dc-40b5-97a3-129f2f331818/search-result-page-throw-error-for-anonymous-user?forum=sharepointsearch

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/d403d030-f5fc-41e9-a41b-ab4154144616/search-does-not-work-for-anonymous-users-in-sharepoint-2013?forum=sharepointsearchprevious

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/346d8bd6-36f3-4877-9e32-f563b65431b0/search-does-not-work-with-anonymous-access?forum=sharepointsearchlegacy